# Import/Export Rhino's 3DM format to/from blender

Tags: export, import, file-format

Is there a plugin to import/export rhinoceros' 3DM files to/from blender?

If there's no plugin yet, would it be possible to write one or are there technical limitations to do such a thing? I suppose somebody would have written something by now...

I'm asking this because I swap files with people who only work with rhinoceros, but most of them only know basic modelling and panic when I start speking about STL file-format.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have successfully imported a 3dm file into Blender on manjaro linux using following plugin : https://github.com/jesterKing/import_3dm

Comment: Worked great, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

It seems there's no direct way to import .3DM files.
However, according to [this tutorial](http://www.studiorola.com/tutorials/miscellaneous/bringing-rhino-files-into-blender-3d/) you can export from Rhino as .LWO (Lightwave) or .3DS (3D Studio). Both can be imported to Blender. .STL export is also an option, I suppose.

Importing to Rhino from Blender should be easier using same formats.

Even if you don't posses a copy of Rhino you can download and use a Full Trial for 90 days.

I'll update if I find a better way of importing to Blender.

Answer (score 1):

A student at GSOC was working on .3dm import into Blender with nurbs capability, but it doesn't appear that there has been any work on the branch since then. It's available on graphicall and it's for mac only.

Otherwise, there are multiple formats that you can use, depending on what you would like to import.

The simplest format to use is obj export from Rhino. However, it doesn't handle blocks/linked data.

If you need to handle blocks, exporting as collada(.dae) works well enough in most cases, although all objects are parented to empties, so if you have thousands of objects, it may slow things down significantly.

Answer (score 1):

### **Rhino Blender Mesh Bridge to import and export quickly**

A time ago I have made a python **Blender bride to Rhinoceros 3D**.
And a **Rhino mesh bridge to Blender**. To help the community now
You can find it on [GitHub **"Blender 4 Rhino"**](https://github.com/ALanMAttano/Blender_4_Rhino). With it, I was able to do [all these models](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/Qz3DwE).

- [LINK](https://github.com/ALanMAttano/Blender_4_Rhino)

**DESCRIPTION**

It is a mesh Blender bridge for Rhino. Let you export the selected mesh from Rhinoceros 3D using a (custom) button. Import that mesh quickly inside Blender (using this plugin script). The python file for Blender let you import and export using one button. In Rhino, pressing right-click on this custom button will import back the Blender mesh.

Hopping that it is still working, please consider improving it.

**LINKS**

- [GitHub Blender 4 Rhino](https://github.com/ALanMAttano/Blender_4_Rhino)
- [Free License](https://github.com/ALanMAttano/Blender_4_Rhino/blob/master/LICENSE)
- [Rhino forum thread](https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/rhino-to-blender-mesh-bridge-import-and-export/94448)