# How to install the add-on to import Rhino .3dm files

Tags: add-on, import

This question/answer seems exactly what I need.

[Import/Export Rhino's 3DM format to/from blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34147/import-export-rhinos-3dm-format-to-from-blender)

But I tried installing import_3dm-master.zip as it suggests, and the rhino3dm-master.zip on which it seems to depend (downloaded zips from GitHub) and don't see a new import format on the File->Import list.

What simple, obvious thing am I missing?

(And I can't just add a comment to that thread because I just signed up and apparently need a 50 to comment. Hmmm.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't download the master branch, instead download the latest release [here](https://github.com/jesterKing/import_3dm/releases/tag/0.0.8) or use the following links to download directly.

Windows: https://github.com/jesterKing/import_3dm/releases/download/0.0.8/import_3dm-v0.0.8.win.zip

Macos: https://github.com/jesterKing/import_3dm/releases/download/0.0.8/import_3dm-v0.0.8.macos.zip

Then install the same way as any other addon. Hope this helps!